# How can I deploy nginx to AWS fargate in code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Say I have a docker-compose file like the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

I want to be able to deploy it to AWS Fargate ideally (although I'm frustrated enough that I'd take ECS or anything else that works) - right now I don't care about volumes, scaling or anything else that might have complexity, I'm just after the minimum so I can begin to understand what's going on. Only caveat is that it needs to be in code - an automated deployment I can spin up from a CI server.

Is CloudFormation the right tool? I can only seem to find examples that are literally a thousand lines of yaml or more, none of them work and they're impossible to debug.

Comment: I've never used Docker compose, but I've built a CD pipeline (using AWS CodePipeline) that builds a Docker image, pushes it to AWS ECR and then deploys to Fargate. So I'd say yeah, using Cloudformation is a good, if at first painful way to go. Here's a setup that might help you get started https://gist.github.com/milancermak/ea079fbd0fab937bdec66136e65a5de0 I've adapted it from one of my projects, it might not be 100% working, but at least the templates passed linting. I guess you'll need modify the buildspec code to work with Docker compose.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [AWS cdk](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/versions/0.23.0/) tool to write your infrastructure as code. It's basically a meta framework to create cloudformation templates. Here would be a minimal example to deploy nginx to a loadbalanced ecs fargate service with autoscaling, but you could just remove the last to expressions. The code gets more complicated quickly, when you need more control about what to start

```
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/cdk');
import ec2 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ec2');
import ecs = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ecs');
import ecr = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ecr');

export class NginxStack extends cdk.Stack {

    constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const vpc = new ec2.VpcNetwork(this, 'MyApiVpc', {
            maxAZs: 1
        });

        const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'MyApiEcsCluster', {
            vpc: vpc
        });

        const lbfs = new ecs.LoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'MyApiLoadBalancedFargateService', {
            cluster: cluster,
            cpu: '256',
            desiredCount: 1,
            // The tag for the docker image is set dynamically by our CI / CD pipeline
            image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerHub("nginx"),
            memoryMiB: '512',
            publicLoadBalancer: true,
            containerPort: 80
        });

        const scaling = lbfs.service.autoScaleTaskCount({
            maxCapacity: 5,
            minCapacity: 1
        });

        scaling.scaleOnCpuUtilization('MyApiCpuScaling', {
            targetUtilizationPercent: 10
        });

    }
}
```

*I added the link to a specific cdk version, because the most recent build for the docs is a little bit broken.*

Answer (score -1):

ECS uses "Task Definitions" instead of docker-compose. In Task Definitions, you define which image and ports to use. We can use docker-compose as well, if we use AWS CLI. But I haven't tried it yet.

So you can create an ECS Fargate based cluster first and then create a Task or Service using the task definition. This will bring up the containers in Fargate.